# I can't write flutter codes on my Vs Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

This has just happened recently when i opened my flutter app in Vscode. The app runs on `flutter run` but all of my codes are greyed out . When i press `Ctrl + F5` to debug app i get a " Choose enviroment " prompt which has no Dart in the list.
Flutter and Dart extensions  are installed.

[image: My tool bar shows plain text on the language option]

My tool bar shows plain text on the language option.

Can someone help please.

Comment: Probably you missing Dart extension.

Comment: On the list of languages to choose dart is not present

Comment: Have you Dart extension for VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Dart extension and restart the VScode.
VScode-->Extensions--> In search 'type dart'--> There you got extension file of dart.
[image]

Select dart and upgrade. After all, this restarts your vscode.